# RadioButtonList SelectedIndexChange Even on pop form

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi all I have a problem with my pop up form in javascript. I using even of `RadioButtonList` my pop up close. So my question is how should I use `RadioButtonList` Even on pop up form without closing?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you are posting back the form and the changes made with javascript haven't been stored in the view state.

One option would be to use an `UpdatePanel` (assuming you mean ASP.NET and not ASP?) around the `RadioButtonList` to prevent a full post back.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

Comment: I am very happy when you got my answer clearly. And thx so much for your answer I'll try my best.